# Keeping comments in cleared range using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Does using

```
.ClearContents
```

in excel vba remove comments from cells?

I'm clearing data from a large spreadsheet, but I have comments in a few cells that I want to keep. What can I use instead?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  It seems like something that would take less time to check yourself than to create a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear()
    'Clear everything from Sheet 1, cell A1
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I does NOT delete the comments. 
But you can check it if you create a backup save about the original file :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use the alternative `.Clear` to avoid your 'extras' being removed.

Example: `Range("A1:B1").Clear`